# Using javafx media class player to play .wmv files

Tags: javafx, media-player, wmv

I developed a Media Player in JavaFx and that plays Media with format **(.mp4)** files.

But, When I try to play **(.MKV)** files, the player is not working.

How to make this player works with **(.MKV)** files?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WmvFileMoviePlayer extends Application{


public static void main (String [] args){
launch(args);
 }

 @Override
 public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
 Group root = new Group();    
try{

Media media = new Media("video/Indian_Sept_2017.wmv");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

root.getChildren().add(view);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();

player.play();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swing. Don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. How do you expect us to help with a code problem without you showing us any code?

Comment: sorry my  mistake

Answer (score 1):

.wmv is not one of the supported media formats of JavaFX. See here:[SupportedMediaTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes)
You could try something like this instead: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx